# Aurelia Dragula how to use the Api instead of custom element

Tags: api, aurelia, dragula

I'm trying to use aurelia dragula.  All the examples I can find use the custom element

```
<dragula-and-drop drop-fn.call="itemDropped(item, target, source, sibling)"></dragula-and-drop>
```

with then having divs that act as sources/targets like this

```
<div class="drag-source drop-target drop-style" data-list="things">
    <compose repeat.for="thing of things" view-model.bind="thing" data-index.bind="$index"></compose>
</div>
```

That is working great, and I can see I can add other function bindings for drag end, etc.  However the documentation shows a bunch of events that Dragula can listen for, but it looks like I'd have to use the API, instead of the custom element, to make use of those.  I can't seem to figure out how to make use of the Dragula object along with divs like above in the view.  For instance...

```
import { Dragula } from 'aurelia-dragula';
...

let dragula = new Dragula();
dragula.on('drag', (el, source) => {
      console.log('started dragging...');
    });
```

doesn't pick up on the drag events from the div above.

I'm pretty new to aurelia, so maybe I'm missing something framework related?
How can I go about using the Dragula API approach instead of the custom element?

Thanks

Comment: this app uses the dragula API instead of a custom element: http://jdanyow.github.io/aurelia-solitaire/

Comment: I hands down recommend using interact.js with Aurelia. All the interact does is enhances drag and drop events, so it makes for an excellent developer experience with Aurelia.

Comment: I've actually written up a blog on how to create this with interact here http://davismj.me/blog/aurelia-drag-and-drop/

Comment: Thanks matthew.  I think im gonna use interact.